# Is this possible to translate this sql query into laravel queryBuilder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Hi i would like to translate this raw sql query into a laravel queryBuilder.
Is this possible ? cause i struggule.

```php
DB::select("SELECT
  u.id as user_id,
-- users.email as email,
   COALESCE(fr.score_total, 0) + COALESCE (fqr.score_total, 0) as score_total
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      fr.user_id,
      SUM(fr.pts_won) as score_total
    FROM
      forecast_results fr
    WHERE
       platform_id = ".$platform->id."
       AND forecast_fixture_id in ({$fixtureIdsRawQuery})
    GROUP BY
      fr.user_id
    ) fr ON (fr.user_id = u.id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      fqr.user_id,
      SUM(fqr.pts_won) as score_total
    FROM
      forecast_quiz_results fqr
     WHERE
       platform_id = ".$platform->id."
       AND question_id in ({$questionIdsRawQuery})
    GROUP BY
      fqr.user_id
    ) fqr ON (fqr.user_id = u.id) WHERE platform_id = ".$platform->id.";")
```

Can you help me to start to write the queryBuilder ?

i have start trying this, but it does not seem to work.

```php
 DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.id as user_id', 'forecast_results.pts_won',DB::raw('SUM(COALESCE(forecast_results.pts_won, 0))'))
            ->leftJoin('forecast_results', 'users.id', '=', 'forecast_results.user_id')
            ->groupBy('users.id','forecast_results.pts_won')
            ->where('users.platform_id','=',1)
            ->simplePaginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DB::raw for your 2 subqueries fr and fqr:

```
DB::table('users')

->select(
    'users.id as user_id', 
    'forecast_results.pts_won',
    DB::raw('COALESCE(fr.score_total, 0) + COALESCE (fqr.score_total, 0) as score_total')
)

->leftJoin(
    DB::raw("(
        ALL YOUR SUBQUERY
    )AS fr"), "fr.user_id", "=", "u.id"
)

->leftJoin(
    DB::raw("(
        ALL YOUR SUBQUERY
    )AS fqr", "fqr.user_id", "=", "u.id" )
)
->where( "platform_id", "=", $platform->id );
```

Comment: Are you sure this could work ?

Comment: Yes! Just try it!